# resizeable div similiar to jsfiddle or browser

Tags: jquery, css, resize

So, I've seen the css resize:both; attribute and it's close to what I'm looking for but not quite.

I'm trying to find something that is just like [jsfiddles](https://jsfiddle.net/) resizeable textareas but with divs.

Where you can grab the side of the element just like the browser on your computer

Is there a plugin or something for this? Or should I just write it myself?

Comment: not hard to find numerous plugins in a web search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making a frame inside it.

There is a frame tag in HTML :
    `<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
      <frame src="frame_a.htm">
      <frame src="frame_b.htm">
      <frame src="frame_c.htm">
    </frameset>`

You can put whole html inside frame aswell.

Comment: Mind ticking the tick?